# Failed to retrieve server version

Tags: visual-studio-2019, visual-studio-2022

I tried this in both `VS2019` & `VS2022`.

Added a new `SQL Server Database` item in the project. In the `Server Explorer`, created the connection.

When I right click on the database and select `New Query`, it shows the error.

I also added another connection to an existing database in my local machine. I can see it's tables.
Here too the same error.

I'm trying to create a local database for my ASP.NET project.

Do I need to install any extensions or Nuget packages?

[image]